# How to invoke the Shutdown dialog in Docky under Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, lubuntu, docky, logout

I want to create a button in `Docky` equivalent to the `Shutdown` button in `LXpanel`.  I have found that I can create a `.desktop` file which runs `lubuntu-logout` and this does the trick.  But when I try to drag that file into docky I get an icon that looks like a document.  When I click on that icon it opens up the `.desktop` file.  I have tried making the `.desktop` file executable.

Any suggestions as to how I can make the button run `lubuntu-logout` instead?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so we can vote you up!

Comment: Here's the link to your revision! http://askubuntu.com/revisions/136471/3

Comment: Now solved!  
  
When you right click in Lubuntu to select Create New>Shortcut you are provided with a dialog box which effectively results in a .desktop file.  However, closer inspection of the .desktop file shows that it does not include the line:  
  
Type=Application  
  
As a result Docky interprets the shortcut as a text file.  It therefore displays an icon that looks like a text document and clicking on it opens up a text editor.  
  
The solution is therefore to edit the .desktop file (say in Leafpad) and add the Type=Application line into the file.

Comment: Hi Rob, can you post that as an answer instead of a comment so we can vote you up?

Answer (score 0):

## Go to `/usr/share/applications/`

Then search for `Shut` and it will bring `Shut Down`. Just drag and add it to your **Docky**

Comment: @RobCorlett try to edit that `.desktop` file and in execute option write `poweroff` and say what you got

Comment: @RobCorlett i think no,just copy that .desktop file and paste it in your home and edit,is he wants root previliges?

Comment: @RobCorlett don't click on it just edit that file and in execution options place `poweroff`,did this done nothing?

Comment: @RobCorlett did you try to search in unity `shut` and click on `Shut Down`. Is it doing something?

Comment: @RobCorlett don't know but try this `/usr/lib/syslinux/poweroff.com`

Comment: @RobCorlett i don't want to try to shutdown my computer so i will advise `/usr/lib/klibc/bin/poweroff`

Comment: @RobCorlett write that link in execution option

Comment: @RobCorlett by edditing `.desktop` file

Comment: @RobCorlett that mean you need to run it with rot privileges

Comment: @RobCorlett even don't know what to do. can you wait for a minute

Comment: Guys - please do not try to have a "conversation" through comments.  Remember the way this site works is to continually edit the Question (& Answer) with new details and observations.  Please can you both do this and delete your comments.  Many thanks.